# Can't run simple application hosting on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-unity-sdk, unity-webgl

I created app in [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com) . In products I add web hosting. Chosen type of app is Unity (WebGL). 
Then I create .7z package build in Unity and upload on developers.facebook.com. I use Facebook platform, WebGL and App Id.

After that I go to Settings -> Basic, click Add Platform -> Facebook Web Games. I turn on Simple Application Hosting and click on 'save changes'. 
But nothing saves and Facebook Web Games component was deleted.
After some experiments I see that nothing saves when I try turn on Simple Application Hosting. But if Simple Application Hosting is switched off everything on 'settings' is saved.

Why can't I use web hosting ? Maybe it's connected with current Facebook changes ?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me....my game already deployed game is not working because of this issue :(